# Android: Replacing < p > and < br / > tags

Tags: android, html

In my case; I'm getting JSON from a website and have to write it in a TextView. And actually done it. But my boss is wanting the text, plain. No paragraphs; no empty lines.

The text is added the website from a web-console. So the website's database is holding them with html tags and I'm getting them with tags too. I used **Html.fromHtml()** method to write it down; and used tagHandler to handle with < li >  tags with some help; but now I have to erase < p > and < br /> tags. Can anybody help? Thank you very much.

Comment: Ok I learned that I cannot do it with tagHandler. TagHandler only runs when a not-known tag shows up. So what I should use now? Do I have to check all the string with using < p > and < br > as delimiters and make a new string with others...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do this way

This will remove all `<html>` tags from string

```
public String getPlainText(String htmlString){
    System.out.println("HII : " + htmlString.replaceAll("\\<.*?>",""));
    return htmlString.replaceAll("\\<.*?>","");
}
```

This will remove only `<p>` and `<br>` tags from string

```
public String getPlainText(String htmlString){
        System.out.println("HII : " + htmlString.replaceAll("\\<p.|\\<br.*?>",""));
        return htmlString.replaceAll("\\<p.|\\<br.*?>","");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you much Biraj. I found this few minutes ago. Only problem is it's deleting all tags. Have to change it now to delete specific tags. Tahnk you again.

Comment: I was trying to write something like your second code. Thank you but it does nothing :/

Comment: which tag you want to remove give the list here

Comment: Try brijesh patel solution. It sounds promising. I just tried it and it works as your requirement.

Comment: I copied it; nothing happened. Changed it; nothing happened... Couldn't understand... OK lets take a look Brijesh's solution..

Comment: Oh.. Brijesh's is not for mine. I have to hold < li >'s

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just use replaceAll?

```
yourString.replaceAll("<p>", "").replaceAll("<br>", "")
```

Comment: I didn't know about this till 5 minutes ago. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

do

```
`String  myString = htmlString.replaceAll("<p>", "");`
```

and

```
`String finalString = myString.replaceAll("<h>", "");`
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this way..

```
public String getPlainText(String htmlString){
    return Html.fromHtml(htmlstring).toString();
}
```

Comment: hey, use this it will remove all html tags and return you plain text.

Comment: Thank you bro but Oh.. this is not for mine. I have to hold < li >'s < strong >'s and some more.